# How to create session in nodejs without using express

Tags: javascript, node.js, session

I'm new in nodejs and I want to create session without using express.

Do you have some links that can be useful for me to how create session? or article to explain me how does session work?

thanks in advance

(forgive me for taking your time)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try redis-sessions:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis-sessions

Comment: I want to create it my selft